# Windowsパスの文字数の数え方について。「パス＋ファイル名の長さ」が256文字以内になるようにしたい

Tags: windows

**Chromeエクステンションで、Windowsにファイル保存しています**。
そのまま保存すると、「パス＋ファイル名の長さ」が256文字を超えることがあります。
そこで、「パス＋ファイル名の長さ」を256文字以内に抑えるために、Windowsパスの正確な長さを数えたいのですが、例えば、下記パスは何文字に該当しますか？

> L:\データ\ダウンロード\download

**取得目的**
JavaScriptで下記のような計算をするために取得したいのですが…

```
fileNameStr = '取得したファイル名',
fileNameStr.substr(0, 256 - windowsPathLength);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)に

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character.

とあります。

- ドライブ名
- コロン`:`
- ルートディレクトリの`\`
- パス256文字
- NUL終端

を含めて260文字です。カウント方法としてはサロゲートペアは２文字となり。より具体的にはUTF-16エンコーディングで520バイトまでとなります。

---

実はファイル名としての制限ではなく、APIが受け付けるバッファーサイズとしての制限なので、あまり厳密ではなかったりします。

- ANSIバージョンの場合、260バイト制限を受けて、日本語Shift_JISで128文字程度になることがあったりなかったり
- Unicodeバージョンの場合、`\\?\`プレフィックスを付けることで32,767文字に緩和されたり
- Windows 10 1607のUnicodeバージョンの場合、設定を行えば`\\?\`プレフィックスを付けなくても32,767文字に緩和されたり

といろいろあります。

Comment: 確認しますがこれはUTF-16換算ですか？サロゲートペアを使用すると二文字分だったりしますか？